# maven ear deploy order

Tags: maven, deployment, ear

Is there any way to tell maven the deploy order of ear files?

I have the following project structure:

```
app
 |- pom.xml
 |
 |- commons (jar)
 |   |-pom.xml
 |
 |- integration (pom)
 |   |-pom.xm
 |   |
 |  ...
 |   |
 |   |-elasticsearch-search-service (pom)
 |      |-pom.xml
 |      |
 |      |-elasticsearch-search-service-bean (jar)
 |      |  |-pom.xml
 |      |
 |      |-elasticsearch-search-service-ear (ear)
 |         |-pom.xml
 |
 |- services (pom)
     |-pom.xml
     |
     |-search-service (jar)
     |   |-pom.xml
     |
    ...
     |
     |-restapi-web (war)
     |   |-pom.xml
     |
     |-services-ear(ear)
         |-pom.xml
```

The *commons.jar* is packaged under the lib folder in each ears.
The *services.ear* calls ejb services from the *elasticsearch-search-service-bean.jar* so *elasticsearch-search-service-ear* must be deployed before *services-ear*.

When I run maven then it tries to deploy *services-ear* at first and of course it fails with *No bean named elasticsearch-search-service-bean/SearchServiceBean is defined: not found in JNDI environment*.

Everything is working fine when I deploy ears manually in a proper order.

I added a dependency into the *service-ear* project like this, but it does not work and the ear is not deployed before the others:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-search-service-bean</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I try to add *elasticsearch-search-service-ear* dependency into the *service-ear* project than the deploy order is fine but I get this exception:

*Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project ...:services-ear:ear:1.0: Failure to find ...:elasticsearch-search-service-**ear:jar**:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced*

How I can tell to maven that start deploying the *elasticsearch-search-service-ear* before the other ears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.

The only one way to tell to maven the deploy order is to define dependencies between poms.

So if I want to deploy *elasticsearch-search-service-ear* before *services-ear* than I need to add a new dependency into *services-ear*.

```
<!-- elasticsearch-search-service.ear needs to be deployed before services.ear -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-search-service-ear</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The two important settings here are:

- scope needs to be "provided", it prevents *elasticsearch-search-service-ear* libraries to be added into the *services-ear*.
- type needs to be "pom", to avoid *Failure to find ...:elasticsearch-search-service-ear:jar*

I hope it helps to anyone who is in the same situation.